# javascript sub-objects and definition patterns

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I have been mauling over this for while now, and wonder if anyone could point me in the right direction.

I have the following object definition:

```
var foo=function(){};
foo.prototype={
  foo1:function(){},
  baz:{
    baz1:function(){}
  },
  bar:function(){
    function privateFunc1(){}
    function privateFunc2(){}
    return {
      bar1:function(){
        //do something using privateFunc1
        //return the result
      }
    };
  }
};

var foobar = new foo();
```

Now, to access the `baz1` sub-method of the `baz` method, I can do `foobar.baz.baz1()`
But to access the `bar1` sub-method of the `bar` method, I have to do `foobar.bar().bar1()` (*Notice the extra parens after `bar`*)

Is there a way of defining the `foo` object so that I can call `bar1` using `foobar.bar.bar1()` (*Notice, no extra parens*), **But** still keep the use of private functions `privateFunc1` and `privateFunc2` within the `bar` method.

Also, please note that I cannot make `bar` a self-executing function because it depends on mutable properties of the `foo` object, which may change after the function has self-executed.

Hope the question was clear enough... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be going in the direction you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/Una9k/1/

```
var Foo = function() {
    this.mutableProperty = "mutable";
    this.bar = new Foo.prototype.Bar(this);
};
Foo.prototype = {
    constructor: Foo,
    Bar:function(context){
        var ctx = context;
        function privateFunc(){
            alert(ctx.mutableProperty);
        }
        return {
            bar1: function () {
                privateFunc();    
            }
        };
    }
};

var foobar = new Foo();
foobar.bar.bar1(); // alerts 'mutable'

foobar.mutableProperty = "changed";
foobar.bar.bar1(); // alerts 'changed'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this might work...

```
function createFooBar() {
   //return foobar   
   var foobar = {
      foo1: function() {},
      baz: {
          baz1: function(){}
      },
      bar: function(){
          function privateFunc1(){}
          function privateFunc2(){}
          return {
              bar1:function(){
                 //do something using privateFunc1
                 //return the result
              }
          }
      }
   };

   foobar.bar.bar1 = foobar.bar();

   return foobar;
};

var foobar = createFoobar();
```

Using the above you could also house your functions on the createFooBar function. So after the above...

```
createFooBar.foo1 = function(){} //and so on...
```

then in the createFooBar function you might refer to foo1 like so...

```
//code in the beginning...
var foobar = {
    foo1: createFooBar.foo1,
//and so on...
```

Additionally, you could ALSO just create a create function on your current foo function...

```
foo.create = function() {
    var fooBar = new Foo();
    fooBar.bar.bar1 = fooBar.bar();
    return fooBar;
}

var fooBar = foo.create();
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to call foobar.bar() immediately:

```
function createFooBar() {
   //return foobar   
   var foobar = {
      foo1: function() {},
      baz: {
          baz1: function(){}
      },
      bar: function(){
          function privateFunc1(){}
          function privateFunc2(){}
          return {
              bar1:function(){
                 //do something using privateFunc1
                 //return the result
              }
          }
      }()
   };


   return foobar;
};
// now you have foobar.bar.bar1()
```

Comment: can't self-execute the function because it depends on mutable properties of the object.